# MYSQL "Division by zero" warnings, strange behavior

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL 8.0.

I created the following tables

```
SET SESSION sql_mode='ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO';

create table Test(
col1 integer,
col2 integer
);

create table Test1(
colA integer,
colB varchar(45)
);
```

I populated them with these values:

```
Test     Test1
1 2      2 a          
3 4      4 b
1 5
1 2
0 4
0 2
```

Now, from other answers, I know that, in general, I cannot rely on short-circuit because SQL is a *declarative* language so you specify *what* you want not *how*: that's left to rdbms optimizer which is free to rearrange the order of conditions.

I executed the following query against `Test` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test 
WHERE  col2/col1>0 AND col1<>0;

SHOW WARNINGS;
```

I have two warnings regarding the two divisions by zero (as expected) and this matches with the order of execution reported in the execution plan of the above query:

```
"attached_condition": "(((`prova`.`test`.`col2` / `prova`.`test`.`col1`) > 0) and 
(`prova`.`test`.`col1` <> 0))"
```

which clearly shows that `col2/col1>0` is checked before `col1<>0`

Then I ran the following query against the above tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test T JOIN Test1 T1 ON T.col2=T1.colA
WHERE  T.col2/T.col1>0 AND T.col1<>0;
```

Also this time I would have expected the warnings about divisions by zero be raised
but, surprisingly for me, they didn't despite the fact that the query execution plan
shows that the condition with division is perfomed before the check of `col1<>0`:

```
"attached_condition": "((`prova`.`t`.`col2` = `prova`.`t1`.`colA`) and 
((`prova`.`t1`.`colA` / `prova`.`t`.`col1`) > 0) and (`prova`.`t`.`col1` <> 0))"
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing an [`EXPLAIN ANALYSE` on the last query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb264a6c22078c879ecaffab12b43136), this is the output:

```
-> Filter: ((T1.colA / T.col1) > 0)  (cost=1.00 rows=0) (actual time=0.047..0.061 rows=3 loops=1)
    -> Inner hash join (T.col2 = T1.colA)  (cost=1.00 rows=0) (actual time=0.039..0.051 rows=3 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (T.col1 <> 0)  (cost=0.23 rows=1) (actual time=0.006..0.015 rows=4 loops=1)
            -> Table scan on T  (cost=0.23 rows=6) (actual time=0.004..0.012 rows=6 loops=1)
        -> Hash
            -> Table scan on T1  (cost=0.45 rows=2) (actual time=0.015..0.019 rows=2 loops=1)
```

The inner actions are executed first. Here we see that the records from `T` are first filtered by `T.col1 <> 0` and only then they are joined with the records from `T1`. This explains why no division by zero occurs. It also makes sense that this filter is applied *before* the join, as that potentially makes the join operation involve fewer records.

Comment: For inner actions you mean actions performed on the single tables before performing joins, am I right?

Comment: Yes, with "inner", I meant the lines in that output that are indented the most. This kind of plan is a tree, where the  leaves of the tree are executed first.

Comment: One last thing. The order of conditions showed by the execution plan of the last query obtained by clicking via GUI on Execution Plan --> View Source is wrong or what?

Comment: I don't think you can make conclusions on the order of conditions in `attached_condition`. It is a less detailed plan.

Answer (score 1):

Some general rules in MySQL:

- AND'd clauses in WHERE are *usually* performed left to right.
- MATCH and SPATIAL tests will be performed before other tests.
- The Optimizer has limited smarts.
- The Optimizer may choose to start with any of the JOINed tables first.
- LEFT JOIN may *or may not* force the 'left' table to read first.
- Subqueries and function calls -- who knows.
- AND has precedence over OR.  That is, `a OR b AND c` means `a OR (b AND c)` but that does not say which will be *performed* first.
- Some of the above items can be determined by `EXPLAIN`, `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and the Optimizer Trace.

Write your SQL defensively!